# Problems working with ryw:blog and user roles

Tags: javascript, meteor, blogs, iron-router, roles

Is my first time working with blogs and roles in meteor, and I´m having several (and weird) problems working with ryw:blog and alanning:roles. I´m managing the roles with mrt:accounts-admin-ui-bootstrap-3 package. 
My main problem right now (I will post the other problems in new threads), is the next one:

The roles looks like is not working properly with ryw:blogs package. I have 2 users. One of each is the "superuser" with **admin** and **blogAdmin** roles assigned (this user have access to "users admin area"). The another user only has assigned **blogAuthor role** but I can view and edit all posts like a blogAdmin user.
I think that´s can be some routing problem (I´m using iron router) because if I refresh the page,  the role works fine and I can only see and edit my own posts. I´m creating my blog from the ryw:blog example app in his github repository [https://github.com/meteor-blog/example-blog-app][1]
The roles are working fine because when I add the roles with mrt:accounts-admin-ui-bootstrap-3, the roles are assigned right in the roles field in the user account collection (checked in the mongoDB console).
All suggestions are wellcome! thanks in advance!

Here is my code

**Router.js**

```
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'layout'
});
Router.route('/', function () {
  this.render('home');
});

Router.route('/users', function () {
  this.render('adminTemplate');
});
```

**server/server.js**

```
 Meteor.startup(function () {
            // bootstrap the admin user if they exist -- You'll be replacing the id later
            if (Meteor.users.findOne("userId"))
                Roles.addUsersToRoles("userId", ['admin']);
            // create a couple of roles if they don't already exist (THESE ARE NOT NEEDED -- just for the demo)
            if(!Meteor.roles.findOne({name: "secret"}))
                Roles.createRole("secret");

            if(!Meteor.roles.findOne({name: "double-secret"}))
                Roles.createRole("double-secret");
        });
```

**lib/blog.js**

```
Blog.config({

      adminRole: 'blogAdmin',
      authorRole: 'blogAuthor',
      title: "Meteor Blog Example",
      syntaxHighlighting: true,
      syntaxHighlightingTheme: 'github',
      blogIndexTemplate: 'blog',
      blogShowTemplate: 'show',
      comments: {
        disqusShortname: 'blogpackage'
      },
      rss: {
        title: 'Example Blog App',
        description: 'This is an example application for meteor-blog package'
      }
    });
```

**client/home.html**

```
<template name="home">
  <div class="container">
    <p class="lead">
      This is an example project using the
      <a href="https://github.com/Differential/meteor-blog">Meteor Blog</a> package.
    </p>
    <p>
      {{> blog}}
      {{> blogLatest num=5}}
    </p>
  </div>
</template>
```

**client/header.html**

```
<template name="header">
  <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a href="/" class="navbar-brand">Meteor Blog Example</a>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
          <li>
            <a href="{{blogPathFor "blogIndex"}}">Blog</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="{{blogPathFor "blogAdmin"}}">Admin Area (must login)</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          {{> loginButtons}}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

**client/blog**

```
<template name="blog">
  <div class="container">
    {{> blogIndex}}
  </div>
</template>
```

**client/show**

```
<template name="show">
  <div class="container">
    {{> blogShow}}
  </div>
</template>
```